# Aggregating geometry features on geometry simplification using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, simplify

PostGIS has [ST_Simplify](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Simplify.html) functionality which gets one multiline as input and returns one output multiline where the general shape of lines are retained while eliminating unnecessary detail.

Instead of one multiline, I have a table with a LineString geometry column (street segment) and an integer column (traffic velocity of that street). I can create a single multiline out of that LineString column and simplify it, but I need to know traffic velocity of simplified geometries too. Is there any tool to aggregate data of integer column into simplified lines?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, the meaning of you question is unclear. You state one capability, then ask about two completely different ones which are unrelated (mapping and aggregation). Please [Edit] your question to choose one capability, expand your question to include your research on the topic, include your SQL, and specify a focused question on the specific problem you are having.

Comment: @Vince Thanks for your help. I edited my question. I will add sample SQL if it was still unclear.

Comment: Read [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-agg.html).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right you should get started with a simple sql query

```
select velocity, st_simplify(geom, 0.1) as geom from lines;
```

Are you sure you want to aggregate lines to one single giant multiline?
If you really need that then you could GROUP BY your velocity column.

```
select
  velocity,
  st_simplify(st_collect(geom), 0.1)
from lines
group by velocity;
```

Comment: @mhsekhavat, did this answer help you?